# Copy file or directory from remote server

Tags: command-line, ssh, remote-server

I try to copy file from remote server to my local machin but it gives following error

ssh: connect to host 103.241.144.137 port 22: Connection refused.

command : scp root@111.111.111:/home/msecondo/public_html/jsp/afterLogin/sachin/PHR/  /localpth/.

Answer (score 1):

"Connection refused" means that there was no process accepting connections at the IP address and port that your client tried to connect to. In this case, it probably means that there is no SSH server running at 103.241.144.137 port 22. Alternately, if the SSH server is running, it may not be listening on the IP address or port that you tried to connect to.

StackOverflow isn't the right site for troubleshooting SSH server configuration. If you have administrator privileges on the remote server, then you should look into how the SSH server is configured and whether it's running. If you're not an administrator on the remote server, you should report this to the administrators so that it can be investigated.